# .htaccess redirect /subpage/ to /subpage?/wp-login

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Trying to use .htaccess rule to do the wp-login JS check on first visit by appending ?/wp-login to the url since it's interferring with Sucuri firewall when using password protection.

I've created a test subdomain to try to get the htaccess redirect to work before using it on the live site:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^protectedpage$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://testing.no11.ee/protectedpage?/wp-login [R=302,L]
```

view here: [testing.no11.ee/protectedpage](https://testing.no11.ee/protectedpage)

**Unfortunately this does not add the query arg to the url. What am I doing wrong here?**
Expected result when visiting page should be https://testing.no11.ee/protectedpage?/wp-login as the browser url.

Full htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^protectedpage$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://testing.no11.ee/protectedpage?/wp-login [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^protectedpage$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://testing.no11.ee/protectedpage?/wp-login [R=302,L]
> ```

This checks that the `QUERY_STRING` is set to `protectedpage`, but in your example it's the URL-path that is `/protectedpage`, not the query string.

You also need to first check that the query string is not already set to `/wp-login`, otherwise you'll get a redirect loop.

However, you've also put the code in the wrong place. Note the WordPress comment that precedes the code block - you should not manually edit this code. This directive also needs to go *before* the WordPress front-controller, otherwise, it's simply never going to get processed.

Try the following instead *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/wp-login$
RewriteRule ^(protectedpage)/?$ /$1/?/wp-login [R=302,L]
```

This matches an *optional* trailing slash on the requested URL, but it redirects to include the trailing slash in the target URL.

(You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine on` directive.)

No need to include the scheme + hostname if you are redirecting to the same. The `$1` backreference simply saves repetition and refers to the matched URL-path, ie. `protectedpage` (without the trailing slash) in this example.

However, this *always* redirects and appends `/wp-login` to this URL - not just the "first visit" - is that really what you require? Otherwise, you need to *somehow* differentiate between "first" and "subsequent" visits (by detecting a cookie perhaps?)

> **UPDATE:** Minor addition: how would one improve this to add `?/wp-login` to all urls that have the page `/subpage/` as parent i.e `/subpage/page-1` and `/subpage/page-2` would result in `/subpage/page-1?/wp-login` etc? I tried using `(.*)` but this delets the subpage from the url...

You could do something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/wp-login$
RewriteRule ^(subpage/[^/]+)/?$ /$1/?/wp-login [R=302,L]
```

The `[^/]+` subpattern matches any character *except* `/` - so only the second path segment, excluding the optional trailing slash. This is similar to `.*`, but this would capture *everything*, including any trailing slash, so would result in a double slash in the redirected URL.

Comment: Interesting enough I added RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/wp-login$
RewriteRule ^protectedpage$ /$0?/wp-login [R=302,L] to htaccess before the Begin wordpress and nothing happens at all.

Comment: It seems to work when I tried your link above. (Try clearing your browser cache, since there is an additional redirect to append a slash?) Note that your URL appears to have a trailing slash, but this is omitted from the example above. If the trailing slash is optional then change the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ to read `^protectedpage/?$` - I'll update my answer. (But note that you should be linking to the canonical URL - which appears to include the trailing slash?)

Comment: Minor addition: how would one improve this to add ?/wp-login to all urls that have the page /subpage/ as parent i.e /subpage/page-1 and /subpage/page-2 would result in /subpage/page-1?/wp-login etc? I tried using (.*) but this delets the subpage from the url...

Comment: I've updated my answer with regards to the `/subpage`.